# How to paste a bunch of lines into a specified template

Tags: templates

Let's say I have a bunch of text lines, like this:

```
Car
Tree
Bike
```

In the end I want to have:

```
[
{
"name": "Car",
"type": "object"
},
{
"name": "Tree",
"type": "object"
},
{
"name": "Bike",
"type": "object"
}
]
```

Is there some tool that can do that? Basically I'd like to specify a template like this:

```
{
"name": "$",
"type": "object"
}
```

where `$` would be replaced by a line from my source text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any text editor with regular expression capability can do it.

Here is an example from Notepad++

- type your list of words
- open replace dialog (CTRL+H)
- for "find what" enter: `(\w+)`
- for "replace with" enter: `{\n"name": "$1",\n"type": "object"\n},\n`
- check "regular expression"
- "replace all"

This doesn't deal with outermost square brackets (`[]`) you need to add them manually

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to script this - PowerShell can do it fairly quickly:

```
$template = $('
{
"name": "###",
"type": "object"
}
')

$alltext = "["

ForEach ($item in (Get-Content C:\Installs\objects.txt)) {
    $alltext += $template -replace "###", $item
}

$alltext += "]"
Write-Host $alltext
```

[image]

This has the added benefit of being able to do multiple replacements by specifying ### in multiple locations.  If you want, you can also utilise multiple replacements with a CSV file.

To do this, ensure you have distinct placeholders and remember that the first line in the CSV file will be headers that are used in your code:

[image]